# How to read parent and children data from SQL?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008, ado.net

Thanks again for all the wonderful answers you have all posted!

I have two tables in SQL. The first defines the parent, and has a primary key column called ParentId. I also have a child table that has a primary key, and a foreign key as 'ParentId'. So the two tables form a one parent - to many children relationship.

The question is what is the most efficient way to pull the parent + child data C# code?  The data has to be read into the following objects:

```
public class Parent
{
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public List<Child> Children { get; set; }
    //  ... many more properties ... //
}


public class Child
{
    public int ChildId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    //  ... many more properties ... //
}
```

If i use the following query I will get the parent and the children at once where each parent will be repeated as many times as many children it has:

```
SELECT
    p.ParentId as 'ParentId',
    c.ChildId as 'ChildId',
    -- other relevant fields --
FROM
    Parents p
INNER JOIN
    Children c
ON 
    p.ParentId = c.ParentId
```

Using this approach I'd have to find all the unique parent rows, and then read all the children. The advantage is that I only make 1 trip to the db.

The second version of this is to read all parents separately:

```
SELECT * FROM Parents
```

and then read all children separately:

```
SELECT * FROM Children
```

and use LINQ to merge all parents with children. This approach makes 2 trips to the db.

The third and final (also most inefficient) approach is to grab all parents, and while constructing each parent object, make a trip to the DB to grab all its children. This approach takes n+1 connections: 1 for all parents and n number of trips to get all children for each parent.

Any advise on how to do this easier? Granted i can't get away from using stored procedures, and I can't use LINQ2SQL or EF. Would you prefer Data Tables vs DataReaders and if so how to use either with approach 1 or 2?

Thanks,
Martin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer pulling all results in one query and just build the tree in one loop

```
    SELECT p.ParentId as 'ParentId', null as 'ChildId'
    FROM Parents p
    UNION ALL
    SELECT c.ParentId as 'ParentId', c.ChildId as 'ChildId'
    FROM Children c

    List<Parent> result = new List<Parent>();
    Parent current;
    while (dr.Read())
    {
      if (string.isNullOrEmpty(dr['ChildId']))
      {
        //create and initialize your parent object here and set to current
      }
      else if (!string.isNullOrEmpty(dr['ChildId']) 
                && dr['ParentId'].ToString().Equals(current.ParentId.ToString())
      {
        //create and initialize child
        //add child to parents child collection
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> Using this approach I'd have to find
>   all the unique parent rows, and then
>   read all the children.

You could just include an `order by p.ParentId`.  This ensures all children from the same parent are in consecutive rows.  So you can read the next row, if the parent has changed, create a new parent object, otherwise add the child to the previous parent.  No need to search for unique parent rows.

Answer (score 0):

I usually make this decision at the table level.  Some tables I need the children often, so I grab them right away.  In other cases accessing the children is a rarity, so I lazy-load them.

Comment: I obviously need the children which is why I was asking the question the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess option #2 would be more efficient bandwidth wise over option #1 (as you're not repeating any data).

You can have both queries in a single stored procedure, and execute the procedure through code using a sqldataadapter (i.e. `(new SqlDataAdapter(command)).Fill(myDataSet)`, where `myDataSet` would contain the two tables).

From there you'd read the first table, creating a dictionary of the parents (in a `Dictionary<int, Parent>`) by ParentId, then simply read each row in the 2nd table to add the children:

```
parents[(int)myDataSet.Tables[1]["ParentId"]].Children.Add(new Child() { etc } );
```

The pseudo code is probably off a bit, but hopefully you get the general idea